# How to write into excel sheet using Selenium script output

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, jxl

I want to print the output into Excel sheet. My Excel fields be like Name, Phone, Address.

My code is as below:

```
public class Cpydata 
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    int i=0;
    @Test
    public enter code herevoid demo()
    {
        while(i<=1000)
        {
        driver.get("test.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxx")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            //System.out.println(Hos_name);
            Object ph=driver.findElement(By.className("tel")).getText();
            System.out.println(ph);
            Object add=driver.findElement(By.className("jadlt")).getText();
            System.out.println(add);
            i++;
        }   
        driver.quit();  
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which tutorials from the Apache POI site (or others) did you follow? Where did you get stuck? What errors? etc

Comment: looks like you havnt tried anything , you can with JXL or apache poi.